# AJAX POST to PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to POST from my program to a separate PHP file, then grab that data and store it into my SQL database. I've checked my code over and over and can't' find what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

### AJAX

```
$(".btn btn-success last").click(function(){
        $.post("go2.php",
        {
             name: "Donald Duck",
             city: "Duckburg"
        },
        function(data, status){
             alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            });
    });
```

---

PHP file (go2.php) w/ SQL code

```
    <?php

include 'connection.php';

$x = $_POST["name"];
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (Username) VALUES ('$x') ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);



?>
```

Comment: You have to echo something back

Comment: Your code has an SQL injection vector and a deprecated API used .

Comment: How come I need to echo something back @adeneo ? I'm checking the SQL database after each execution for any update

Comment: Should provide more detail on what is or isn't working. You haven't specified if the request is being made or not , if any errors are thrown etc. Use browser dev tools/console to inspect request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the long version of ajax request

```
$(document).ready( function () { 
        $(".btn btn-success last").click(function(){                        
            $.ajax({ 
               type: "POST",
               url: "go2.php", 
               data: {name:"Donald Duck", city:"Duckburg"},
               success: function(data){
                    document.getElementById('divId').html(data);
               }
            });
        });
    });
```

For the echo data, you have to echo a message in your go2.php like "Success"

Comment: there is no `echo` in javascript

Comment: where does `findElementById` come from?

Comment: changed,  going to sleep

Comment: no error being thrown, just my DB is not updating with the info being POSTED

Comment: still no luck with this long version of the AJAX request.

Comment: Well this is not an UPDATE statement you have you know ?

Comment: @xNeyte sorry for my miswording, I was meaning to say that It's not INSERTING the new data into the DB

Comment: Have you tried to type your statement in your database software to check if it is working : INSERT INTO users (Username) VALUES ('test')

Comment: @xNeyte yes, I'm querying and inserting at other points as well, so I know the DB is fine. scroll up and read my last comment and the link to the application. Maybe that'll paint a better picture of my problem

Answer (score 1):

From your code ..

you need to learn a little bit more about selectors

```
$(".btn btn-success last") // what is btn-success ID or Class and 

//What is last ID or Class for id use #btn-success for class use .btn-success
```

before you insert anything to php file check if this file already connected with js or not .. and with the next code you should get alert with 'file already connected'

```
 $(".btn .btn-success .last").click(function(){
        $.post("go2.php",
        {
             name: "Donald Duck",
             city: "Duckburg"
        },
        function(data){
             alert(data);
            });
    });
```

and in php

```
<?php 
echo('file already connected');
?>
```

Most important thing to know what is a (.last) is that a button or form or anchor

if .last is form

```
$(".btn .btn-success .last").on('submit',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

if .last is button or anchor

```
$(".btn .btn-success .last").on('click',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
  });
```

hope it will help

Comment: I think it would be more clear if you seen the actual demo I'm working on. It's a SPA, so I really can't echo anything back when making the POST. I understand selectors and what not, it's just not reaching my PHP file and I dont understand why. Since it's SPA, I've been testing a echo by having it write data to a file when it reaches the go2.php file

Comment: check out my demo at http://www.justinsamuels.info/structures/Steps/index.html and click all the way to STEP 4. The data being entered, I need it to be POSTED so I can retrieve it and store into a SQL database

Comment: is the go2.php directory is the same with your index.html?